# записать GridView.name в переменную

Tags: devexpress, delphi-xe

delphi. При экспорте в эксель использую стандартный метод ExportGridToExcel.
Перед экспортом cxgridview присваиваю другую вьюху где данные представлены по другому, но после экспорта нужно вернуть gridView которая была активна.
Какого типа нужно переменная что бы записать в нее GridView.Name

Comment: Разве не TString?

Comment: дело в том что я хотел потом по этой переменной показать вьюху которая была активна перед экспортом. frmRashDebet.grRashDebetLevel1.GridView := Variable, вот чтот тип такого. но я уже через if then else запилил. переменная типа string а потом через оператор выбора сравнивал имя и выбирал действия

Comment: вот таким путем я решил свой вопрос grid := frmRashDebet.grRashDebetLevel1.GridView.Name;                         
 if grid = 'grRashDebetDBBandedTableView1' then
            frmRashDebet.grRashDebetLevel1.GridView := frmRashDebet.grRashDebetDBBandedTableView1